# Reaching object that is declared inside a component from another component - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, javascript-objects, react-animations

I'm building a small grammar app. I simplified it here, at [snacks](https://snack.expo.io/@uygarucar/samplesentences-workingsample_09-48)

***What the above app does so far***

The app fetches and prints sample sentences according to our choices of article and noun genders.

***Aim***

My aim is, whenever a type of word is chosen (article or noun), to light up the color of the type of word chosen. (For example, **if definite article chosen, make `'The'` yellow for a few seconds in the sample sentence**). And then return the article/noun to black as the rest of the sentence is.

***My Try***

I've declared the `animatedTextColor` variable in a separate file

```
//TextColorAnimation.js
...
let animatedTextColor = textColor.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ["rgb(170, 188, 16)", "rgb(0,0,0)"]
    })
    //sending to redux store
    dispatch(setTextColorAC(animatedTextColor))
...
```

to be used in `SampleSentencesEnglish` object's style.

```
//SampleSentences.js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  article: {
    color: animatedTextColor
  }
})
const SampleSentencesEnglish = {
 'masculine': {
   'indefinite': <Text>
                  <Text style={styles.article}>A </Text>
                  <Text>man </Text>
                  was looking for you
                 </Text>,
...
```

I've wrapped `styles` and `SampleSentencesEnglish` inside a component to be able to use `useSelector`

```
//SampleSentences.js
...
const SampleSentences = (props) => {

            const animatedTextColor= useSelector(textColorSelector);

            const styles = StyleSheet.create({
                    article: {
                        color: animatedTextColor
                  }
            })
                    
            const SampleSentencesEnglish = {
              'masculine': {
                'indefinite': <Text>
                                <Text style={styles.article}>A </Text>
                                <Text>man </Text>
                                was looking for you
                              </Text>,
...
}

export {SampleSentences}
```

Now, problem is, **I cannot reach the** `SampleSentencesEnglish` **object that is inside a component from another component** in `MainApp.js`

```
  //MainApp.js
  ...
  import {SampleSentences} from './Examples/SampleSentences';
  ...
   <View>
      ...
       <Text>Sample Sentence</Text>

       //Invoking object fails
       <Text>{SampleSentences.SampleSentencesEnglish[currentNounType][currentArticleType]}         
      </Text>
  </View>
```

[Here](https://snack.expo.io/@uygarucar/samplesentences-notworking) is a not working version.
It has `TextColorAnimation.js` and `TextColorRedux.js` files as extra content and has module in `SampleSentences.js` comparing to first link.

Thanks for reading. Hope it is understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not making `SampleSentencesEnglish` its own component and pass the data you need to it from `MainApp` component in the `props`.

Something like:

```js
// in MainApp component
... useSelector
... useState
...
render() {
    return (
        ...
        <SampleSentencesEnglish
          currentNounType={currentNounType}
          currentArticleType={currentArticleType}
          styles: {styles}
        />
        ...
    );
}
```

And in `SampleSentencesEnglish` maybe something like:

```js
const SampleSentencesEnglish = props => {

  const englishSamples = {
    'masculine': {
      'indefinite': <Text>
                     <Text style={props.styles.article}>A</Text>
                     <Text>...</Text>
                    </Text>,
      'definite': <Text>...</Text>,
    },
    ...
  }

  return (
    ...
    {englishSamples[props.currentNounType][props.currentArticleType]}
    ...
  )

}

export default SampleSentencesEnglish;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I've solved the problem using your way.